# Ordinal arithmetic and limit ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Suppose $1\leq\xi<\omega_1$ is a countable ordinal and that $1\leq\zeta<\omega^\xi$.  Is it always true that $\zeta+\omega^\xi=\omega^\xi$?  If so, why?

Comment: Yes. As a hint, look separately at the cases where $\xi$ is a limit or a successor. The limit case is very simple and in the successor case knowing something about ordinal subtraction helps.

Comment: Thank you for verifying that it is true, however I still would like to know why it is true.  (Alternatively, if someone has a reference, that would be sufficient.)  Apparently, since $\omega^\xi$ is a limit ordinal, then by definition we have $\zeta+\omega^\xi=\sup_{\alpha<\omega^\xi}\zeta+\alpha$.  So, it would be sufficient to show that $\zeta+\alpha<\omega^\xi$ for all $\alpha<\omega^\xi$.  But I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose first that $\xi$ is a limit ordinal, so that $\omega^\xi=\sup_{\eta<\xi}\omega^\eta$; then

$$\zeta+\omega^\xi=\sup_{\eta<\xi}(\zeta+\omega^\eta)=\zeta+\sup_{\eta<\xi}\omega^\eta=\zeta+\omega^\xi\;.$$

Now suppose that $\xi=\eta+1$. Then $\omega^\xi=\omega^\eta\cdot\omega$, so $\zeta+\omega^\xi=\zeta+\omega^\eta\cdot\omega$. Since $\zeta<\omega^\xi$, [there is a unique ordinal $\alpha$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Subtraction_when_Possible_is_Unique) such that $\zeta+\alpha=\omega^\xi$; clearly $\alpha\le\omega^\xi$. Suppose that $\alpha<\omega^\xi$; $\omega^\xi=\sup_{n\in\omega}\omega^\eta\cdot n$, so there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $\zeta<\omega^\eta\cdot n$ and $\alpha<\omega^\eta\cdot n$. But then

$$\zeta+\alpha\le\omega^\eta\cdot n+\omega^\eta\cdot n=\omega^\eta\cdot(2n)<\omega^\xi\;,$$

which is impossible. Thus, $\alpha=\omega^\xi$, and $\zeta+\omega^\xi=\omega^\xi$.